# Age Verification PHP

Tags: php, html, html-select

I'm using a script that works wonderfully to verify age for a website I'm working on. Currently it's using a dropdown menu to select the Month, Day, Year. I was hoping it was possible to change the dropdown to have the user input the Month, Day, Year instead.

Here is the code:

```
                <?php

            define('MIN_AGE', 21); // Enter the minimum age that your website visitors must be to view your content (replace 18 with your number)
            define('COOKIE_DAYS', 30); //Enter the number of days you would like the cookie to last (replace 30 with your number)

            // BE CAREFUL EDITING ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE //

            date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
            function get_birth_drops($year = '', $month = '', $day = '')
            {
                $out = '';

                $year = $year ? $year : '';
                $month = $month ? $month : '';
                $day = $day ? $day : '';

                $month_select = '<label>MM: <select name="bmonth" id="bmonth"><option value=""></option>';
                for($i = 1; $i <=12; $i ++)
                {
                    $selected = ($i == $month) ? ' selected':'';
                    $month_select .= '<option value="' . $i . '"' . $selected . '>' . $i . '</option>';
                }
                $month_select .= '</select></label>';

                $day_select = ' <label>DD: <select name="bday" id="bday"><option value=""></option>';
                for($i = 1; $i <=31; $i ++)
                {
                    $selected = ($i == $day) ? ' selected':'';
                    $day_select .= '<option value="' . $i . '"' . $selected . '>' . $i . '</option>';
                }
                $day_select .= '</select></label>';

                $year_select = ' <label>YYYY: <select name="byear" id="byear"><option value=""></option>';
                for($i = 2010; $i >= 1950; $i --)
                {
                    $selected = ($i == $year) ? ' selected':'';
                    $year_select .= '<option value="' . $i . '"' . $selected . '>' . $i . '</option>';
                }
                $year_select .= '</select></label>';

                $out = $month_select . $day_select . $year_select;

                return $out;
            }

            function calculateAge($birthday){
                return floor((time() - strtotime($birthday))/31556926);
            }
            ?>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Explain a bit more please, bit confused

Comment: So... you want us to do the work? What is the salary?

Comment: @Thomas The OP might be looking to replace the `<select>` with input fields instead.

Comment: *"I was hoping it was possible to change the dropdown to have the user input the Month, Day, Year instead."* - **Well sure it's possible!** Yet since there is no actual "problem" here, and just code reformatting, this is not the place to ask questions like this. We try to help "fix" code, not "build" it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use text input fields instead:

```
//Month input field instead of select field
$month_select = '<label>MM: <input type="text" name="bmonth" id="bmonth" value="' . $month . '" /></label>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the function `get_birth_drops` outputs the three fields as select elements. To change them to a text input simply change the variables storing the select field html:

Example:

```
$month_select = '<label>MM: <input type="number" name="bmonth" id="bmonth" /><label>';
```

However, this wont validate the data so you will probably want to include some JavaScript to handle that. Validation can be done using HTML5 as well:

Example:

```
$month_select = '<label>MM: <input type="number" min="1" max="31" name="bmonth" id="bmonth" /><label>'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, @user1056677 this worked perfectly. Very much appreciated for the help!